# How to create an Azure policy to block creation of Azure StorageAccount Queues?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-policy

Currently I am working on a policy set that I can use in Azure to allow/disallow resources.
In my policy I try to enforce a rule that allows the creation of a storageaccount but not of Queues and Tables in it. Blob and Files are ok.

A simple policy of which I assume it would block the creation of a Queue in the storage account does not work:

```
resource policyBlockResourceTypes 'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions@2020-09-01' = {
  name: '${policyConfigurations.policyBlockResourceTypes.name} - test2'
  properties: {
    displayName: '[${policyConfigurations.policyBlockResourceTypes.name}] BlockResourceTypes - test72'
    policyType: 'Custom'
    mode: 'All'
    description: 'Policy to whitelist resource types'
    metadata: policyConfigurations.policyBlockResourceTypes.metadata
    policyRule: {
      if: {
          field: 'type'
          like: 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices'
      }
      then: {
        effect: 'deny'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried changing 'like' to 'equals' but unfortunately it yields the same result - I am still able to create Queues.

I used [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/queueservices/queues?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) as a reference to the type. Please note I also tried 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues' but that also does not work.

Does anyone have a solution to implement such a policy or is aware of some limitations with policies?

Kind regards and thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below **Azure policy** will deny the creation of any new queue in the storage account.

**Azure Policy**

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

You can check the policy compliance status in the Azure portal to see if the policy is being enforced.

[image]